# how to get cellular connection data

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I can not find any plugin to get android cellular data (I want to know first if My connection is of type 2G, 3G or 4G then at least I want to get my signal strength and some other info but those 2 are very important).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is plugin available for check internet connection state in different parameter.like downloading and uploading data speed.
[internet_speed_test](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test#-readme-tab-)

Like this,

```
Var unitText = unit == SpeedUnit.Kbps;
```

Comment: HI thanks You for ur Answer but I know that plugin and I've already test but I need the signal strenght (in dbm ) not the internet speed (in Mbps or Kbps).  like in android studio:      
 mSignalStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
 mSignalStrength = (2 * mSignalStrength) - 113; // -> dBm